# new Date() 12/24 hour format JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

I have a simple validation that should prevent Time In/Out of entering incorrect values. So if user pick for example:

`12:30 PM = Time In` and `12:15 PM = Time Out`

They will get the message on the screen `'Time Out can not be  less or equal than Time In'`.

My validation works fine but in one case. For example user pick:

`Time In: 12:30 PM` and `Time Out: 1:00 PM`

They click save and alert message popup. I found that my code was producing something like this:

```
Time In: Thu Sep 15 2016 00:29:00 GMT-0500 (Central Standard Time)Time Out: Wed Sep 14 2016 13:29:00 GMT-0500 (Central Standard Time)
```

I used JavaScript to create new Date for Time In and Time out values. Looks like my code is setting 00 for 12 PM hours in `new Date()`. So my question is how to prevent that or is there any other way in JavaScript to fix this problem. Here is my code where I'm taking two entered values in converting to new Date() :

```
var timeIn = document.getElementById('timeIn').value;
var timeOut = document.getElementById('timeOut').value;
var today = new Date(),
  curYear = today.getFullYear(),
  curDate = today.getDate(),
  curMonth = today.getMonth(),

  defaultTimeIn = timeIn.split(":"),
  defaultTimeOut = timeOut.split(":"),

  defaultHourIn = parseInt(defaultTimeIn[0], 10),
  defaultHourOut = parseInt(defaultTimeOut[0], 10),

  defaultMinAMPMIn = defaultTimeIn[1].split(" "),
  defaultMinAMPMOut = defaultTimeOut[1].split(" "),

  defaultMinIn = defaultMinAMPMIn[0],
  defaultMinOut = defaultMinAMPMOut[0],

  defaultAMPMIn = defaultMinAMPMIn[1],
  defaultAMPMOut = defaultMinAMPMOut[1];

if (defaultAMPMIn == "PM") {
  defaultHourIn += 12; //hours are in 24-hour format (0-23)
}

if (defaultAMPMOut == "PM") {
  defaultHourOut += 12; //hours are in 24-hour format (0-23)
}

var compTimeIn = new Date(curYear, curMonth, curDate, defaultHourIn, defaultMinIn);
var compTimeOut = new Date(curYear, curMonth, curDate, defaultHourOut, defaultMinOut);

if (compTimeIn >= compTimeOut) {
  alert("'Time Out' can't be less or equal to 'Time In'");
}
```

Comment: Would this work properly with a different locale?

Comment: @ppeterka I'm not sure.

Comment: You could take a look at http://momentjs.com/. It's probably a best library for manipulating date/time in javascript. You will save a lot of hassle with it.

Comment: "include momentjs library in order to use that?" yes

Comment: Can you make this a snippet? Or what values should `timeIn` and `timeOut` be, as you have given what appear 2 different format possibilities.

Comment: I listed above in my question what values look like. Time In: 12:30 PM and Time Out: 1:00 PM. I use am/pm format time in my time picker.

Comment: You also say "So if user pick for example `12:30 PM = Time In` and `12:15 PM = Time Out`"

Answer (score 2):

12-hour clock to 24-hour clock, hour + period conversion.

```js
function to24Hour(hour, period) {
  if (period === 'AM' && hour === 12) {
    hour -= 12;
  } else if (period === 'PM' && hour < 12) {
    hour += 12;
  }
  return hour;
}
const hours12 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
const hours24 = [];
for (let hour of hours12) {
  hours24.push(to24Hour(hour, 'AM'));
  hours24.push(to24Hour(hour, 'PM'));
}
console.log(hours24);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your condition from:

`defaultAMPMOut/In == "PM"`

to

`defaultAMPMOut/In == "PM" && defaultHourOut/In != 11 //or 12 depending on if it starts at 0 or 1`

What's happening is if it's 12, then it's still adding 12 when it shouldn't be, rolling it over to 0.

**EDIT:**

If it's 12AM, you also have to subtract 12 hours so it's 0

```
if (defaultAMPMIn == "PM" && defaultHourIn != 12) {
  defaultHourIn += 12; //hours are in 24-hour format (0-23)
}

if (defaultAMPMOut == "PM" && defaultHourOut != 12) {
  defaultHourOut += 12; //hours are in 24-hour format (0-23)
}

if (defaultAMPMOut == "AM" && defaultHourOut == 12) {
  defaultHourOut -= 12; //hours are in 24-hour format (0-23)
}

if (defaultAMPMIn == "AM" && defaultHourIn == 12) {
  defaultHourIn -= 12; //hours are in 24-hour format (0-23)
}
```

Comment: I tested code above and works for me. I'm not sure if that will prevent any other error with the time conflicts. Looks like 24 hour never gonna be hit. If I pick 12AM it will display 12 hours.

Comment: You should have a check if it says AM and is 12, make it 0 or 1

Comment: So inside of my if(defaultAMPMOut/In == "PM" && defaultHourOut/In != 12) I should check for 12 am and subtract in that case?

Comment: Different if statement. `if(defaultAMPMOut/In == "AM" && defaultHourOut/In == 12)` subtract 12 because 12AM is the same as 00:00

Comment: No problem! Glad to help.

Comment: here's a jsfiddle with the above answer https://jsfiddle.net/rgdahsms/1/

Answer (score 1):

Why not do something simpler and convert this into a re-usable function, something like:

```
var time = document.getElementById('timeIn').value;
var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
var minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
var AMPM = time.match(/\s(.*)$/)[1];
if(AMPM == "PM" && hours<12) hours = hours+12;
if(AMPM == "AM" && hours==12) hours = hours-12;
var sHours = hours.toString();
var sMinutes = minutes.toString();
if(hours<10) sHours = "0" + sHours;
if(minutes<10) sMinutes = "0" + sMinutes;
alert(sHours + ":" + sMinutes);
```

Comment: This is an example and is meant to guide, not do the code for you :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
  // Your Code
    if (defaultAMPMIn == "PM" && defaultHourIn >12) {
                defaultHourIn += 12;//hours are in 24-hour format (0-23)
            }

            if (defaultAMPMOut == "PM" && defaultHourOut >12) {
                defaultHourOut += 12;//hours are in 24-hour format (0-23)
            }
   //Your Code
```